# When is monero "unlocked balance" updated?

Tags: transaction-confirmation, unlocked-balance

I just sent some coins out and now my unlocked balance is zero, but my balance shows a positive. How long do I have to wait to get it to update my unlocked balance?

Comment: Kind of duplicate of that ^ question.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a dublicate from [here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3262/whats-the-difference-between-balance-and-unlocked-balance?rq=1).

You would need to wait 10 blocks, or about 20 minutues until your wallet shows the coins as balance and not as unlocked.